# Unity how to display Highscores 1-9?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on my unity project and I have high-scores from 1-9 saved in my PlayerPrefabs. I get them like this:

```
private SortedList<string, int> GetHighScores()
{
    SortedList<string, int> tempList = new SortedList<string, int>();

    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
    {
        string tempName = "Highscore " + i;
        tempList.Add(tempName, PlayerPrefs.GetInt(tempName));
    }

    return tempList;
}
```

However, how can I display them in a good way?
I guess I could create 1 text object for each high-score, but that would create a lot of games objects and seems like a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using the [`Text`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Text.html) component not `OnGUI()` or anything from the [GUI](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUI.html) class.

> However, how can I display them in a good way? I guess I could create
>   1 text object for each high-score, but that would create a lot of
>   games objects and seems like a bad idea.

Object Pooling would have been fine here but, since you **only** need `9` texts, simply create arrays of `Texts`. When you want to show high scores, load your scores by calling the `GetHighScores()` function, then loop over the array of `Texts` and store the result to them. You can then set `Text.enabled` to `true` to show the `Texts`.

To hide the scores, simple loop over the Text array then set each one to empty string then set `Text.enabled` to `false`.

The script deblow implements what I said above. Just create 9 texts from the Editor, change High Scores size to `9` and drag each `Text` to the Element slots in order.

```
public Text[] highScores;

public void hideHighScore()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        highScores[i].text = "";
        highScores[i].enabled = false;
    }
}

public void showHighScore()
{
    SortedList<string, int> hScores = GetHighScores();
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        string tempName = "Highscore " + (i + 1);
        highScores[i].text = hScores[tempName].ToString();
        highScores[i].enabled = true;
    }
}

private SortedList<string, int> GetHighScores()
{
    SortedList<string, int> tempList = new SortedList<string, int>();

    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
    {
        string tempName = "Highscore " + i;
        tempList.Add(tempName, PlayerPrefs.GetInt(tempName));
    }
    return tempList;
}
```

Since you know the amount of data you need to store which is 9, there is no reason to use `SortedList` or `List`. You can just use array for that and prevent the unnecessary memory allocation performed while using `SortedList`.

Comment: I never thought of that you could just do Text[] clean and simple, and i'll change from a sorted list to an array. Cheers.

Comment: You can probably just put all the text ui objects into a container and disable/enable that. And on disable you most likely don't even need to change it because you change it before enabling.

Comment: @GunnarB. Yeah, He could do that. Put it into a panel then enable or disable the panel. Also he doesn't need `highScores[i].text = "";`. I had it there to make Text empty while disable. Not sure that is useful.

Comment: @JoakimCarlsson Glad you found it helpful. Since you want to use array, I already did that. Here you go http://pastebin.com/Qk62y75E It is much more efficient than what is in this answer now. Happy coding!

Comment: @Programmer Yeah, that's what I did. I did put all the text objects in a Canvas so I can also scale it too the screen. Cheers for the help.

Answer (score 0):

For starters 9 text objects isn't that much but you could make just one and have the values on different lines.

You could also display the value with GUI.

```
int s1 = 43, s2 = 32;

void OnGUI() {

    GUI.Label(new Rect(20, 20, 100, 500), "Score 1: "+s1+"\n Score 2: "+ s2);

}
```

You can also create a scoreboard if for example you are holding down TAB like in Battlefield and Call Of Duty and enable/disable it.

Comment: I was hoping I could get all the highscores from my PlayerPrefab put them into a list and just loop them in a FOR loop and print it like that. Using GUi.Label I have to make a variable for each score, so s1, s2,s3,s4,s5,s6,s7,s8, s9. Which is rather ugly imo. But if there is no other way I have no option I guess.

Comment: @JoakimCarlsson You should be able to create labels in a for loop. Or add to an existing label.

Comment: You can make a function that takes one parameter, and that's the value you are changing saves the PlayerPrefs value into a temporary variable and updates the text then you call that function every time you change the value. Btw if you have a lot of values consider loading/saving from a .txt file because PlayerPrefs isn't completely stabel with a lot of values.

Comment: @GunnarB. Of course I can create labes in a for loop, how ever doing it would just overlap the other label like this. SortedList<string, int> highScoreList = GetHighScores();
                foreach (var score in highScoreList)
                {
                    GUI.Label(new Rect(20, 20, 100, 500),"\n" + score.Key + score.Value);
                }

Comment: @JoakimCarlsson Just offset the (y-) position of the label. This is easier with a normal for loop, just use something like `newRect(20, 20 * (i + 1), ...)`.